# How would i define my interface for this JSON data coming from action?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

How would i define my interface for this JSON if i want to access the data present in the data object here:

```
items:
data: Array(1)
0: {reactionType: Array(1), _id: "5d46f4cd5f68325378603144", name: "ravi", email: "nischals@ravi.com", phone: 12345678, …}
}
length: 5
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

im doing like this:

```
  name: String;
}
export interface items {
  items: {
    data: Array<Object>;
  };
}
export interface SettingCategoryAddItemProps {
  addItem: Function;
  getItem: Function;
  items: items;
}
```

But doesnot work

Comment: what do you mean by *But does not work*?

Comment: Please, expan and format your JSON, help the community to help you

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to prefix an interface name with `I` in typescript. From your JSON I can do this:

```
export interface IData {
  reactionType: any[]; // Better create a type for any
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  ....
}

export interface IItems {
  items: {
    data: IData[],
  }
}

export interface ISettingCategoryAddItemProps {
  addItem: (item: any) => void; // Better create a type for any
  getItem: (itemId: string) => object; // // Better create a type for Object
  items: IItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try used this

```
    export interface data  {
    reactionType:any[],
    _id:string,
    name:string,
    email:string,
    phone:string,
    ...

  }
  export interface items  {
    items:{
        data:data[],

    }
  }
  export interface SettingCategoryAddItemProps {
    addItem: (item:any)=>{if want to show any thing as conforme or not};
    getItem: (itemname:string)=>{item };
    items: items;
}
```